# Parsing the JSON data in swift

Tags: swift

I have a JSON data that i fetched from my database.

```
"JSONs": [
{
  "id": "cpz44e1h",
  "Number_of_Parents": 2,
  "tag": "variational_linear_regression",
  "Child": [],
  "Number_of_Childs": 0
},
{
  "id": "mnj2e4z2",
  "Number_of_Parents": 0,
  "tag": "asymptotic_complexity",
  "Child": [
    {
      "Child_Number": "1",
      "Child_Id": "jfrdulg7",
      "Child_Name": "np_complexity_class"
    }
  ],
  "Number_of_Childs": 1
}]
```

Now I need to fetch the name of child. But I am not able to do so. The code breaks off every time I try and says unexpectedly found nil while wrapping an optional value. Here is the code that I wrote for the purpose. Can somebody help.

```
let json = doc.body();
                let arrStudentsData1 = json["JSONs"] as [[String:AnyObject]]


  for student1 in arrStudentsData1 {
                let arrStudentsData2 = json["Child"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
                  println(arrStudentsData2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get data back from the server it comes back as an optional value. You need to make a check to see that what you think is there is actually there.

so

```
if( json!["JSONs"] != nil ) {
    //do work and more checks here
}
```

if we don't do this, then every time we assume we got the data we needed we might not have.. since it's optional

I'd also try printing the json object itself.

```
println(json)
```

this will give you an idea of what you received back

Comment: yes i did tried that but actually when i print the arrStudentsData1. Its fetching the complete doc. But when I tried printing the arrStudentsData2 it gives the error that i am talking about. Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, `json["Child"]` should read `student1["Child"]`

```
let json = doc.body();
                let arrStudentsData1 = json["JSONs"] as [[String:AnyObject]]


  for student1 in arrStudentsData1 {
                let arrStudentsData2 = student1["Child"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
                  println(arrStudentsData2)

}
```